# Como colocar duas action com HTTPPOST

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Como colocar dois controladores com HTTPPOST

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(string Nomel, string Utilizador, string Password, string PasswordC)
{

}

 [HttpPost]
 public ActionResult Index(string Nome, string Email, string Message)
 {
 }
```

> The current request for action 'Index' on controller type
>   'HomeController' is ambiguous between the following action methods:
>   System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult Index(System.String, System.String,
>   System.String, System.String) on type Cinel.Controllers.HomeController
>   System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult Index(System.String, System.String,
>   System.String) on type Cinel.Controllers.HomeController

Comment: Assim mesmo, mas isso não chama controlador, se chama ação (_action_). Qual é a sua dúvida?

Comment: Se eu colocar isso ele dá erro so funciona se um for Post e o outro get

Comment: A resposta ficou clara?

Comment: Não exatamente, não sei bem o que fazer para corrigir

Comment: Não pode ter duas Actions com o mesmo nome e `HttpPost`, você precisa mudar o nome, ou uma deve ser `HttpGet`

Comment: @AmadeuAntunes Trocar o nome, jovem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Na declaração do `Controller` use `RoutePrefix`, ficaria asism:

```
[RoutePrefix("api/service")]
public class ServiceController : ApiController
```

Nas funções você deve declarar da seguinte forma:

```
[Route("enviar")]
public ActionResult Enviar(string Nome, string Email, string Message)
{
   // seu codigo
}

[Route("receber")]
public ActionResult Receber(string Nome, string Email, string Message)
{
  // seu codigo
}
```

Desta forma o que irá definir se é um `Post` ou `Get` é a utilização dos parametros.

Este formato também aceita parâmetros na rota, ficaria assim:

```
[Route("receber/{id:string}")]
```

Answer (score 1):

Veja o que diz o erro (destaque feito por mim):

> The current request for action 'Index' on controller type 'HomeController' **is ambiguous between the following action methods**: System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult Index(System.String, System.String, System.String, System.String) on type Cinel.Controllers.HomeController System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult Index(System.String, System.String, System.String) on type Cinel.Controllers.HomeController

Você não pode ter duas ações com o mesmo nome desta forma.

Porque quando fizer uma chamada a aplicação não vai saber se chama a primeira ação com o último parâmetro como `null` ou se chama a segunda ação.

Você só precisa usar um nome diferente para suas *actions* ou definir rotas diferentes para elas.

Answer (score 1):

O problema esta relacionado com `ActionResult` nao aceita dos metodos com o mesmo nome, pq essa class esta relacionada com sua view, e a mesma coisa dizer que existe 2 arquivos com o mesmo nome no mesmo lugar.

o class Index é apenas para carregar o conteudo da pagina e nao serve como um metodo get para ser chamado todo hora

correcao:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
 return view()
}

 [HttpPost]
 public ActionResult Enviar(string Nome, string Email, string Message)
 {
   // seu codigo
 }

 [HttpGet]
 public ActionResult Receber(string Nome, string Email, string Message)
 {
   // seu codigo
 }
```

caso precise de um tutorial recomendo a propria asp.net : https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/getting-started/introduction/accessing-your-models-data-from-a-controller