# ASP.NET - Como utilizar multiplos métodos post em um mesmo controller?

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, mvc, controller

Estou com o seguinte problema:

Em uma determinada página HTML tenho dois botões que chamam métodos POST diferentes em um mesmo controller.

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("UserInfo1", "UserInfo", FormMethod.Post))
{
    <input type="submit" value="Ir para Action" 
     name="botao1" id="botao1" />
}

@using (Html.BeginForm("UserInfo2", "UserInfo", FormMethod.Post))
{
    <input type="submit" value="Ir para Action" 
     name="botao2" id="botao2" />
}
```

O código no meu controller é o seguinte:

```js
using Project1.Classes;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace Project1.Controllers
{
    public class UserInfoController : Controller
    {
        [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult UserInfo()
        {
           return View();
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult UserInfo1(string g)
        {
            @Viewbag.User1 = g;
            return View();
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult UserInfo2(string g)
        {
            @Viewbag.User2 = g;
            return View();
        }
    }
}
```

A rota configurada para esse controller é:

```
routes.MapRoute(
            name: "UserInfo",
            url: "profile/",
            defaults: new { controller = "UserInfo", action = "UserInfo", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
```

A grande questão é que ao pressionar os botões NÃO estou sendo redirecionado para os métodos UserInfo1 e UserInfo2 (Percebo isso quando tento executar a operação inserindo breakpoints nesses métodos). Consequentemente recebo um erro 404 na página HTML.

Como posso fazer para eu possa acessar cada um desses métodos? é necessário criar algum tipo de rota especifica?

Comment: Coloque todo Codigo do Controller

Comment: código do Controller atualizado @Virgilio Novic.

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Como colocar duas action com HTTPPOST](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/281735/como-colocar-duas-action-com-httppost)

Comment: Você não tem a rota Default?

Comment: Bardetta. Não uso uma rota default. Se esse for o problema, como devo configurá-la?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Complementando...**

Está dando erro por conta da falta da rota *Default*, pois a sua configuração rotas ele sempre entra no *controller* e *action* **UserInfo**.

```
routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
    );
```

Valeu lembrar também que a rota `Default` deve sempre vir por ultimo, pois ele sempre irá entrar na primeira rota que "bater"

Answer (score 2):

O seu problema é que você não tem Action do tipo HttpGet para suas view serem carregadas.

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult UserInfo1()
{
    return View();
}
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult UserInfo2()
{
    return View();
}
```

Para cada Action UserInfo1 e UserInfo2 você precisar ter uma View com o mesmo nome para que o mvc ache ela quando a action for chamada.

Veja como ficou [controller](https://github.com/MarconcilioSouza/Exemplos-de-Codigo/blob/master/Exemplos-Asp.Net.MVC/Exemplos-Asp.Net.MVC/Controllers/UserInfoController.cs) e [Views](https://github.com/MarconcilioSouza/Exemplos-de-Codigo/tree/master/Exemplos-Asp.Net.MVC/Exemplos-Asp.Net.MVC/Views/UserInfo)

Comment: Tentei aqui mas não funcionou. Entendo que esse seria o problema caso a execução estivesse acessando algum dos posts, no entanto ele sequer chegar a entrar dentro dos métodos POST para retornar a view.

Answer (score 0):

Consegui resolver. 
O problema é que faltava a rota padrão, que deve ser colocada abaixo das rotas personalizadas:

```
routes.MapRoute(
        name: "UserInfo",
        url: "profile/",
        defaults: new { controller = "UserInfo", action = "UserInfo", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
    );

routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
```